# How to configure kubernetes kub-dns to reach external net?

Tags: minikube, kube-dns

I tried examples via windows minikube.

at minikube ssh, I can ping google.com.

but at Inside the container, I cant ping yahoo.com , what should i do?

Need help please.

Regards.

[This is logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNNwB.png)

Comment: This is more of a question for https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed at minikube version: v0.24.1